# how to perform background task in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to perform network check, and if the device is online then i should trigger a post request even if the application is running in the background.

I found that react-native-sync-adapter library will help me to do that. but when i tried to implement app is force closing every time

below is my code.

//index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('TASK_SYNC_ADAPTER', () => App);
```

//App.js

```
import SyncAdapter from 'react-native-sync-adapter';

useEffect(() => {
  SyncAdapter.init({
    syncInterval,
    syncFlexTime,
  });
}, []);
```

please help me to find the issue

Answer (score -1):

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('TASK_SYNC_ADAPTER', () => App);

I'm also looking for some answers regarding this library, but in your case I think I know enough to say this is your problem. You're saying your Headless JS task is the App itself, and I'm guessing calling that is what's crashing your app.